# What is the license for libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

Tags: qt, gcc, licensing, mingw

can't find out what the license for the libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is? one of our developers has given me a program that includes this dll and I don't know if I can use it within our application.
I think he has developed it using QT creator and MinGW.
anyone know the license for this dll?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgcc is a part of GCC which mean it's under GPL licence, for more information:
[The GCC low-level runtime library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html)

Comment: I think there's an exception for libgcc so it can be statically linked without contaminating the code.

Comment: It is under GPL with exception for using it with GPL-incompatible software: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1-faq.en.html